# Strip date from filename using batch script

Tags: date, batch-file, rename, filenames, strip

I have  multiple files with dates on them I would like to strip.

> exOpTimer01232018.txt
>
> exOpProcess01232018.txt
>
> exOpFac01232018.txt
>
> exOpProd01232018.txt

I would like to have a batch script remove the date and leave result such as

> exOpTimer.txt
>
> exOpProcess.txt
>
> exOpFac.txt
>
> exOpProd.txt

These are monthly file and the date stamp changes every month.

I have tried doing

```
RENAME C:\temp\*????????.txt *.txt
```

But wasn't successful.

Comment: Use a loop to set each files name, _(without extension)_, to a variable then remove the last eight characters from that variable before appending the files extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example based on my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where .:exOp*.txt 2^>Nul') Do Call :Loop "%%A"
Pause
Exit

:Loop
Set "fName=%~n1"
Ren %1 "%fName:~,-8%%~x1"
```